# How to use the "command" command when using gdb in emacs?

Tags: emacs, gdb

[image]

I use gdb in emacs.

The "command" command is used to set commands to be executed when a breakpoint is hit.

It should return when I type "end" as below, but nothing happened.

But when I use gdb in shell, it is ok.

So who can tell me why?

Comment: I think there's a bug where Emacs doesn't recognize abbreviations.  Try using `commands` (with the "s") and see if that works.

Comment: That's the answer! Thank you!